# When to leave out の?

Tags: particles, particle-の

> マスク大手 24時間態勢で増産 新型ウイルス肺炎感染拡大で

*from [here](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20200121/k10012253491000.html)*

In this sentence the words 新型 and ウイルス form the meaning "a new type of virus". But shouldn't 新型 be connected using の? I have seen this pattern a lot of times, but when are you allowed to leave out the particle?